# Redshift Running SUM challenge

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Given the following data sample, I'm trying to perform a running sum() isolated to date, account_no, service.  Hoping someone here can help.

```
snapshot_dt             | account_no | account_name | service | cost_one
2022-02-22 00:00:00.000 | 00001      | name_1       | svc_1   | 0.10
2022-02-22 00:00:00.000 | 00001      | name_1       | svc_2   | 0.10
2022-02-22 00:00:00.000 | 00001      | name_1       | svc_3   | 0.10
2022-02-22 00:00:00.000 | 00002      | name_2       | svc_1   | 0.10
2022-02-22 00:00:00.000 | 00002      | name_2       | svc_2   | 0.10
2022-02-22 00:00:00.000 | 00002      | name_2       | svc_3   | 0.10
2022-02-22 00:00:00.000 | 00003      | name_3       | svc_1   | 0.10
2022-02-22 00:00:00.000 | 00003      | name_3       | svc_2   | 0.10
2022-02-22 00:00:00.000 | 00003      | name_3       | svc_3   | 0.10
2022-02-23 00:00:00.000 | 00001      | name_1       | svc_1   | 0.10
2022-02-23 00:00:00.000 | 00001      | name_1       | svc_2   | 0.10
2022-02-23 00:00:00.000 | 00001      | name_1       | svc_3   | 0.10
2022-02-23 00:00:00.000 | 00002      | name_2       | svc_1   | 0.10
2022-02-23 00:00:00.000 | 00002      | name_2       | svc_2   | 0.10
2022-02-23 00:00:00.000 | 00002      | name_2       | svc_3   | 0.10
2022-02-23 00:00:00.000 | 00003      | name_3       | svc_1   | 0.10
2022-02-23 00:00:00.000 | 00003      | name_3       | svc_2   | 0.10
2022-02-23 00:00:00.000 | 00003      | name_3       | svc_3   | 0.10
...
```

I started with this code:

```
with _data as (
    select
        snapshot_dt
        , sum(cost_1) as total_cost_1
    from my_table 
    group by snapshot_dt
)
select 
    snapshot_dt
    , sum(total_cost_1) over (order by snapshot_dt rows unbounded preceding) as running_cost_1
from _data
```

The above worked as expected but then I wanted to see if I could add in other data features such as account_name and service such that I could get specific running costs by snapshot_dt, account_name, or service.

I tried adding these data features in with some grouping statements and ultimately what appeared to happen was a running total based on prior row, I suspect related to `rows unbounded preceding`.

Comment: What's the ordering criteria for the running sum?

Comment: I would assume it has to be `snapshot_dt` because I'm looking to develop a forecasting model, which I have working, based on snapshot_dt.  All I want to do now is bring in additional data features so I can forecast (over time) by specific account or service.

Comment: Just add account name and service to your query and also in a Partition By clause in the second sum() unless I don't understand what you want.  Also, where did start_dt come from in the above query?

Comment: @Eric "I would assume it has to be snapshot_dt..." -- At least in the sample data most rows have the same `snapshot_dt` so it's not possible to order by that column and, there's no way of producing a running total.

Comment: I replaced start_dt with snapshot_dt, it was a copy+paste mistake.  I'll take a look at the partition by clause.  -Thanks!

Comment: @TheImpaler The date differs by 1 day, 2022-02-22, 2022-02-23.  The full dataset has ~15000 rows, I truncated.

Comment: @ChrisMaurer unless I'm missing something, I simplified a bit to test `sum(cost_1) over (partition by "account_name") ` does not appear to work.  To try and explain, what I was hoping to accomplish is getting a running total of cost_1 of 0.60 if I filter on name_1, or (if my math is correct) 1.80 if looking at all by snapshot_dt (3 accounts * 3 Svcs * 2 days).

Comment: No Partition by inside the cte.  Add the partition by account name to the second, exterior sum, `sum(total_cost_1) over (Partition by account_name Order By snapshot_dt rows unbounded preceding)`

Comment: @ChrisMaurer Got it, so I implemented with `sum(cost_1) over (partition by account_name order by snapshot_dt rows unbounded preceding)` and everything seems to be working as expected.  Then I added service, `sum(cost_1) over (partition by account_name, service order by snapshot_dt rows unbounded preceding)` and things broke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original code with all the places you need to include account_name and service in between double-stars (**).  Take out the double stars and it be fine:

```
with _data as (
    select
    snapshot_dt, sum(cost_1) as total_cost_1
    from my_table 
    group by **account_name, service,** snapshot_dt
)
select **account_name, service,** snapshot_dt
, sum(total_cost_1) over (Partition By **account_name, service,** order by snapshot_dt rows unbounded preceding) as running_cost_1
from _data
** Order By account_name, service, snapshot_dt **
```

Comment: Thank you, this works however I have found issues with it when leveraged in Tableau.  There may be something I can do in Tableau to address this and I was able to reproduce what Tableau is doing in SQL by wrapping the query with another `select sum(running_cost_1) from (<query here>) group by snapshot_dt, account_name, service`